# check each character from a string by pgsql function

Tags: function, postgresql

I want to make a function which will check each character of a string. 
For example, lets take a word "pppppoooossssttt", in this case the function will return a warning if same character repeated for more that 2 times. Here 'p' is repeated for 5 times. So the function will return a warning message.

Comment: Ok, and what did you try till now ?

Comment: till now i have split the string into individual characters but cant able to compare each character if they are repeated or not.       
MY QUERY IS : select regexp_split_to_array(statename,'') into var_one from state where statecode=$1 order by statecode;

Comment: Ok, you can get it by looping into the array, and return a warning message if a last 3 characters are same...

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to install plpython on your setup, this is what I would do.  Then you could simply place this test inside a "WHERE" clause of a standard SQL function.  It's immutable so it will only be called once, and it always returns True so it won't affect the results of a SQL query.  Postgres has had some pretty shaky python implementations but either they or EnterpriseDB cleaned things up in the latest release.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION two_or_less(v text)
RETURNS BOOLEAN AS $$
    #If the string is two characters
    #or less, we can quit now.
    ct = len(v)
    if ct < 3: 
        return True

    import plpy
    warned = set()

    a,b,c = v[:3]
    for d in v[2:]:
        if a == b == c:
            if a not in warned:
                warned.add(a)
                plpy.warning('The character %r is repeated more than twice in a row.' % a)
        a,b,c = b,c,d
    return True

$$ LANGUAGE 'plpython3u' IMMUTABLE;
```